# Data join in a line chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm very new to d3, so goal #1 was to show the chart. This works with the following code:

```
const line = d3.line()
  .x(d => this.x(d.x))
  .y(d => this.y(d.y));

console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data), 'color', color);
// data [{"x":"2017-07-01T04:00:00.000Z","y":81.2},{"x":"2017-08-01T04:00:00.000Z","y":79.6},{"x":"2017-09-01T04:00:00.000Z","y":79.4},{"x":"2017-10-01T04:00:00.000Z","y":80.6},{"x":"2017-11-01T04:00:00.000Z","y":80},{"x":"2017-12-01T05:00:00.000Z","y":76}] color blue
g.append('path')
  .datum(data)
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('stroke', color)
  .attr('d', line);
```

With this code, anytime I run this method again, I get a new line, which is expected since I'm appending. I want to update only the `stroke` and `d` attributes when I have new data and/or color, I replace the code after the `console.log` with:

```
const lines = g.selectAll('.line').data(data);
lines.enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'line');
lines
  .attr('stroke', color)
  .attr('d', line);
```

I don't see the line anymore, not at first, not after updates.

I'm including a codepen with the code in this question: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJaVNM?editors=0010

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Please don't misuse the `d` tag. It's for the D programming language.

Comment: @greenify, sorry about that, I didn't mean to add the `d` tag. I was trying to add the `d3v4.js` instead. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper data join would be:

```
  // give data an array, each part of the array is an array representing a line (ie path)
  let lines = g.selectAll('.line').data([data]); //<-- notice array

  // you have lines entering, .merge this back to the update selection
  lines = lines.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .merge(lines);

  // lines variable is now enter + update
  lines
    .attr('stroke', color)
    .attr('d', line);
```

Updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PEoaBM?editors=0010)

Comment: You can now do this in one call with d3's selection.join - see my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028595/how-to-use-enter-data-join-for-d3-line-graphs/62795539#62795539