# How to use enter (data join) for d3 line graphs

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to understand how we can go about using data joins with line graphs. Most examples I see use datum(), rather than data() with our data join, and a direct mapping of the line function when appending the path element. I think we prefer using datum() in this case because the entire line function is sort of a single path.

To understand data joins more though, I would like to see how I could make this work for a single line graph, but the snippet I try below does seem to work.

My code:

```
var dataset = [50, 80, 40, 30, 20];

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0,4])
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d); });

// ** Works just fine, as expected **
// svg.append("path")
//  .datum(dataset)
//  .attr("d", line)
//  .attr("class", "line");

// Does not work
svg.selectAll("path")
    .datum(dataset)
    .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: when you do `append` there **is** a node to attach the datum to. when using `selectAll` there is no node yet so you need `data()` to crate placeholders.

Comment: @rioV8 but even when we want to update the existing line graph, we dont use selectAll() or enter().append() on our data points. I think whats happening here is that unlike in other graphs where you have an element created for every data point, here we have a single line element for all the data points

Answer (score 4):

The trick with lines is that you are building a single svg `path` rather than a number of individual svg shapes like you would with most other kinds of visualisations like bar charts.

So you need a *single* data item, consisting of all the points needed for your line, for the d3 join logic to work:

```js
svg.selectAll("path")
   .data([dataset])
   .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
```

Or if you want enter/update/remove logic, using the recent (d3.join)[https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_join] pattern:

```js
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data([dataset])
    .join(
      enter => enter.append("path").attr("class", "line"),
      update => update,
      exit => exit.remove()
    )
    .attr("d", line); // and other attributes that change on enter/update here
```

The `enter` function is only called if `[dataset]` has changed.  The `.attr("d", line)` logic is called on both enter and update.